# updat_field not working for advanced custom field 's postobject

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

i have post object tht needs to be set or updated based on the text i m using **update_field** for the same but **it doesn't update the selected value for the post object in the post**

```
<?php

$allposts= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'genres', 'numberposts' => -1));
$newgenre="MYSTERY";

foreach ( $allposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
if (!empty($post))
    {
    update_field('genrelist',$newgenre,$post->ID);  
    }

endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written out, albeit less performant than you may like, *should* work based on [the `update_field()` documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/). You might consider trying the following:

- Verify that 'genrelist' is the meta key being used by the custom field
- Try swapping out 'genrelist' for the field key (see "[Finding the field key](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/#finding-the field key) for instructions on how to reveal this) to ensure it's not a reference lookup issue.
- Your call to `get_posts` is setting the post type to 'genres', but that seems much more likely to be a taxonomy than a custom post type. You may want to verify that `$allposts` isn't giving you an empty array (which would mean the `foreach` loop with the `update_field()` calls is never executed).

For whatever it's worth, since you're not using functions like `get_the_ID()` in the code you've provided, you don't need to worry about `setup_postdata()`. The check for `empty()` seems unnecessary as well, since `get_posts()` shouldn't be returning empty posts. Rewritten, the example code is more like this:

```
$allposts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'genres', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) );
$newgenre = 'MYSTERY';

foreach ( $allposts as $single_post ) {
  update_field( 'genrelist', $newgenre, $post->ID );
}
```

FWIW, setting `numberposts/posts_per_page` equal to '-1' can be a huge performance issue if your site has lots of posts. It's better to set a reasonable upper-limit (in the rewritten code, I used 100, but your limit might vary). For more information, [10up has open sourced their best practices for WordPress development](https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/) (full disclosure: I work for 10up).